# Display a widget on a specific type of archive

Tags: widgets, conditional-tags

I have two sidebar widgets, I need to display 1 widget on the archive pages for the standard post categories and the other widget needs to show on just the archive pages for a specific custom post type.

If I use the conditional tag is_archive() then both widgets will show up on both archive pages.

How can I determine which archive page the widgets should be displayed on?

I'm using the plugin 'Widget Logic'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [is_tax()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) function to accomplish this.

The first parameter, the taxonomy slug is optional, but you do want to specify it. This would be something like `product-categories`. The second, a specific term, is also optional. It'd be perfectly acceptable to have the following:

```
is_tax('product-categories');
```

Answer (score 0):

(is_archive()&&(get_post_type()=='projects'))

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?